# PHP - MVC Render View

Tags: php, model-view-controller

Im using a custom MVC built by me..

Im fairly new to this approach, and im having some trouble to understand all of this.

My website has a login system that allows the users to log in in any page(view).

What i want to do is:

After the user logs in, the controller will render the view he was on before the call to the controller login function.

So header is out of the options since i need to send a view to be rendered

Does anyone has a solution to do this?

Comment: You are in control of your own framework. You can use any number of methods for tracking where the user came from. A get referral, for example. session last page visited, etc. Header is always an option unless you have no control of the code or just did things incorrectly.

Comment: I dont want to add the login function to all controllers and therefore all models.. Just want to use the specific controller for the login. And have a way to know what view was the user on

Comment: You wouldn't add login to each controller. You would just make your login pass the referral with the login fields. There's no reason you can't grab the current url and post it as a hidden field

Comment: @KaiQing header will not work because i dont have full views, just partial views( e.g. header, footer, content) and when i render my View will render the three, so header would just show like a form or the content of a page

Comment: @KaiQing really didnt thought about that, seems like a good solution :)

Comment: even if you have partial views, your MVC pattern should run controller first, which should process the login before any view is rendered. Easiest would be posting to the login controller directly, which never renders a view, then header the user back to where they came from with a success or fail message

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you track the where the user came from in a session variable?
Session is always available.
Sessions are not accessable to anyone outside you're system.